# How to continue this proof for the minimum principle for Laplace's equation?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, maximum-principle

I know we can prove the minimum principle by using the maximum principle, by replacing $u(x,y)$ by $-u(x,y)$, but I keep getting stuck. Can someone help me figure out how to continue?

So we have Laplace's equation $$u_{xx}+u_{yy} =0$$ and to prove the minimum principle, we let $$v(x,y) = -u(x,y) + \epsilon (x^2+y^2)$$ and let $\min u(x,y) = m$ and $\min (x^2+y^2) =l$.

From this, we get that $$v(x,y) \geq -m + \epsilon l$$. This is where I keep getting stuck. I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly or incorrectly, but I can't get further than this to prove that $u(x,y) \geq m$ as $\epsilon$ goes to $0$.

Can someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong or what to do ahead? (Also really sorry for this basic question, but please bear with me, I'm really trying ;-;)

Comment: Are you trying to work through the proof of the maximum except with $u$ replaced with $-u$? Or are you happy that the maximum principle is true and are wondering how you obtain the minimum principle but replacing $u$ with $-u$ in the maximum principle?

Comment: I understand how the maximum principle is true. But, the set of notes I was looking at said that the minimum principle can be obtained by replacing $u$ by $-u$, and left it as an exercise, but while doing it, I can't figure out how to proceed forward? So mostly the second thing you said.

Comment: I also am not sure if I should add or subtract $\epsilon$. At the end, I still come back to the conclusion of the maximum principle somehow, so I'm sure I'm doing something really wrong, but I really can't figure out what... :/

Comment: @JackT's point is probably that if you're happy to take the maximum principle as read, then you don't need to be messing with $\epsilon$s at all. But if you want to prove the (weak) minimum principle from scratch, you can show that $u_{xx}+u_{yy} = 0$ implies that $v=u-\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)\epsilon$ satisfies $v_{xx}+v_{yy}<0$, that that implies $\min_{\bar{\Omega}}v=\min_{\partial \Omega}v$ and that that implies $\min_{\bar{\Omega}}u=\min_{\partial \Omega}u$ in turn.